# Can anyone provide information on the meaning of iface in sar reports?

Tags: linux, networking

We are running a Hadoop cluster (RedHat Linux 7.9), HBASE on HDFS, and we want to try to track `sar nw` stats back to the originating source applications.

On worker nodes (which contain hbase region servers and hdfs datanodes), sar reports ~80% of IPv4 traffic on the loopback port (`iface=lo`, resolves to 127.0.0.1 in `ifconfig`), with remaining ~20% traffic on the host ip address (`iface=bond0`, resolves to host ip address in ifconfig).

This is the opposite of what we are expecting, we expect most of the traffic on `bond0`, but this isn't what sar reports.

Question: Can anyone provide information on the meaning of `iface` in `sar` reports? Is there any possibility that OS routes traffic on the local host IP to the loopback?

Comment: "Is there any possibility that OS routes traffic on the local host IP to the loopback?" – [Yes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408332/108618).

Comment: hey thanks for coming back - can you explain how this happens?
thanks v much for your time on this, mr

Comment: I gave you the link, I cannot explain better than the answer the link points to.

Comment: thanks, sorry missed the link b4 - mr

Answer (score 0):

"iface" here simply means your network interfaces. It refers to a network interface card (NIC) or adapter that connects your computer to a network